Can facio be used to express visiting someone?
In Duolingo's Latin course, they have examples like the following:

Cliens patronum facit.

The answer they expect you to choose is, "the client visits the patron". Can facio be used to mean "visit" in this construction? I wasn't familiar with this and checking L&S didn't catch that usage.

I remember Duolingo having "iter facit" to mean visit, I don't remember "facit" by itself.

I remember seeing "Cliens salutationem facit" in Duolingo. I found this from Google search.

@qrsngky Does that even mean "visit a patron," though? I checked PHI and three examples it has all refer to military greetings.

@cmw I'm not sure about it, but I'm pretty sure it's not *patronum facit in Duolingo. Wiktionary has "a ceremonial visit by a client to his patron" as meaning #2 but I haven't checked its sources

Since my original post I went through further lessons and It does have "Cliens salutationem facit," so I think I was remembering incorrectly. However, the correct "answer" for that phrase according to Duolingo was "the client visits the patron."

@qrsngky I think this is where the creators of Duolingo got mixed up. Salutatio is the actual greeting in the morning, but when it's used that way, it's not idiomatic to use facere to indicate making the visit, but for making a formal greeting between armies.

Looking through PHI, I see no obvious relationship connecting clients, patron, and facere.
Nor is there a specific entry for "visit" under facere in the OLD. The closest I see is with a time word as an object, and then it means "to spend [x amount of time] (somewhere)," such as servus...annum in fuga fecerat, "the slave...had spent a year on the run."
I might have overlooked something, but this feels off to me, as if the makers had left out a critical word or two.
Are you sure you didn't misread the Latin? There are Duolingo cards online that have "cliens patronum visitat", which is better, though seemingly not attested.
